# XML in C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, xml, c++builder, data-storage

How can I use **XML as a simple data storage** in Borland C++ Builder 6?

Is there an internal class, which I could use?

Thank's for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the `TXmlDocument` is implemented in C++Builder 6, but a more simple solution would be to use the [TinyXML [1]](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) library, which is indeed simple, and easy to use. I have used it with different versions of C++ Builder and it works like a charm.

[1] http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/

Comment: TXMLDocument is exactly what I was looking for.. Couldn't remember the exact class name :-D thanks

Answer (score 0):

use NativeXML

---

```
xmlDoc = new TNativeXml("test");      
xmlDoc->EncodingString = "GB2312" ;
xmlDoc->XmlFormat = xfReadable;
xmlNode = xmlDoc->Root->NodeNew("report") ;
xmlNode->WriteString("date","2008-6-8") ;
xmlNode->WriteString("road0","10") ;
xmlNode->WriteString("road1","8") ;
xmlNode = xmlDoc->Root->NodeNew("ctrParm") ;
xmlNode->WriteString("parm0","0") ;
xmlNode->WriteString("parm1","1") ;
xmlNode->WriteString("parm2","2") ;
xmlDoc->SaveToFile("test.xml") ;
delete xmlDoc ;
```